# Android: Crashlytics not sending report c++ library crash

Tags: android, crash-reports, crashlytics

I have an Android app which has a C++ library (via JNI).

Whenever the library crashes, it makes the app also crash, but I don't receive the crash on crashlytics.

**Is this a limitation of [Crashlytics](https://www.crashlytics.com/). Does it only catches the uncaught Java exceptions?**

*Note: Any Java exception on main thread that makes the app crash is caught by Crashlytics, so I know it is working.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now it's official, [Crashlytics supports NDK](http://crashlytics.com/blog/the-wait-is-over-launching-crashlytics-for-android-ndk?utm_source=Crashlytics%20Customers&utm_campaign=90ed18ae1d-introducing_crashlytics_ndk_5_29_2015&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_3330fdbe2e-90ed18ae1d-97406981)!

Answer (score 2):

If you read their blog:
http://www.crashlytics.com/blog/crashlytics-february-2015-update/

They say:

> Latest Toys from Crashlytics Labs : Many of you who are building awesome apps with the NDK on Android have
>   requested support from Crashlytics. Since opening access to our beta
>   program in October, our Labs team has continued building this out and
>   enhancing its functionalities every day. We’re now working with top
>   companies who have already shipped their apps with our beta — so if
>   you haven’t test out our NDK beta yet, request early access here

You can get the beta access here:
http://try.crashlytics.com/secret/

Edit:
We been using the beta for some time now and it does the trick nicely. It's now out to the general public and you can read their [blog post](http://crashlytics.com/blog/the-wait-is-over-launching-crashlytics-for-android-ndk) about it.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that the Android SDK only catches Java exceptions at the moment. Twitter announced that Crashlytics has NDK support coming soon, though.